# CSS - absolute positioning SVG (IE)

Tags: css, svg, position

I tried to position to simple SVG shapes with absolute position. It seems to work fine in Firefox, Google Chrome but not in Internet explorer (I don't have any mac to test in safari... if someone can confirm). There is also a little issue with the triangle bottom SVG which is not correctly to the right (1px is missing apparently)

What is wrong and how can I correctly position SVG?

Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/g5zqrdxx/3/

html:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="triangle-top">
        <svg width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
            <polygon points="0,1 1,0 0,0" />
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="triangle-bottom">
        <svg width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
            <polygon points="1,1 1,0 0,1 1" />
        </svg>
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    background: #444444; 
}
.triangle-top {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.triangle-top svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    fill: red;
}
.triangle-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.triangle-bottom svg {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    fill: green;
}
```

Comment: *I don't have any mac to test in safari* You don't need Mac to use Safari :)

Comment: Yes maybe but it doesn't solve the problem with IE...

Comment: It works fine on Chrome. Can you poste an image?

Comment: Yes, I know but not in Internet explorer

Comment: As for IE, if you look at your console , you'll see : **SVG Point list has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed.** So there's something wrong about your svg's?

Comment: Indeed, I see it. But I don't understand what can I do. Everything seems normal but not in IE.

Comment: Even with a svg without error it doesn't works. I really don't understand. Maybe it's an issue with IE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used an alternative solution with pure css to obtain the same result.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/g5zqrdxx/5/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="triangle-top">
        <div class="triangle-up-left" style="border-color:red"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="triangle-bottom">
        <div class="triangle-down-right" style="border-color:red"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    background: #444444; 
}
.triangle-top {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.triangle-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.triangle-up-left {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    padding-left: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-up-left:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -500px;
    border-bottom: 500px solid transparent;
    border-left: 500px solid;
    border-left-color: inherit;
}
.triangle-down-right {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-down-right:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top:-500px;
    border-top: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid;
    border-right-color: inherit;
}
```